# Trouble Calling Terms from Function

Tags: function, matlab, ode45

I have a code that defines a function, then I try to use the variables I defined within that function in another expression. When I do this, I get an error that is:

```
Undefined function or variable 'phi'.
```

I'm not sure why phi is undefined, since I have it in the if/else statement.

It might be better to explain with my (shortened) code:

```
global I11 I22 I33 Mx My Mz w10 w20 w30 eps10 eps20 eps30 eps40...
       C110 C120 C130 C210 C220 C230 C310 C320 C330 IC K0

IC = [w10 w20 w30...
      eps10 eps20 eps30 eps40...
      C110 C120 C130 C210 C220 C230 C310 C320 C330];

opts  = odeset('RelTol', 1*10^(-10),'AbsTol', 1*10^(-10)); 
[t, y] = ode45(@(t,y) DynEqn2(t,y,I11,I22,I33,Mx,My,Mz), [ti tf], IC, opts);

N = sqrt(sum(y(:,4:7).^2,2));  


kap = acosd(1-2*y(:,5).^2-2*y(:,7).^2);

phi1 = acosd((2.*(y(:,4).*y(:,5)+y(:,6).*y(:,7)))/sind(kap));
phi2 = asind((2.*(y(:,6).*y(:,4)-y(:,5).*y(:,7)))/sind(kap));

if phi1==phi2
    phi = phi1;
elseif phi1==180-phi2
    phi = phi1;
elseif -phi1==phi2
    phi = -phi1;
elseif -phi1==180-phi2
    phi = -phi1;
else
    disp('Something is wrong with phi')
end


figure (1)
plot(t,phi)

figure (2)
plot(t,kap)


function soln = DynEqn2(t,y,I11,I22,I33,Mx,My,Mz)
w1 = y(1);
w2 = y(2);
w3 = y(3);

eps1 = y(4);
eps2 = y(5);
eps3 = y(6);
eps4 = y(7);

C11 = y(8);
C12 = y(9);
C13 = y(10);
C21 = y(11);
C22 = y(12);
C23 = y(13);
C31 = y(14);
C32 = y(15);
C33 = y(16);

w1_dot = (Mx - w2*w3*(I33-I22))/I11;
w2_dot = (My - w1*w3*(I11-I33))/I22;
w3_dot = (Mz - w1*w2*(I22-I11))/I33;

eps1_dot = .5*(w1*eps4-w2*eps3+w3*eps2);
eps2_dot = .5*(w1*eps3+w2*eps4-w3*eps1);
eps3_dot = .5*(-w1*eps2+w2*eps1+w3*eps4);
eps4_dot = -.5*(w1*eps1+w2*eps2+w3*eps3);

C11_dot = C12*w3-C13*w2;
C12_dot = C13*w1-C11*w3;
C13_dot = C11*w2-C12*w1;
C21_dot = C22*w3-C23*w2;
C22_dot = C23*w1-C21*w3;
C23_dot = C21*w2-C22*w1;
C31_dot = C32*w3-C33*w2;
C32_dot = C33*w1-C31*w3;
C33_dot = C31*w2-C32*w1;


soln = [w1_dot; w2_dot; w3_dot; ...
        eps1_dot; eps2_dot; eps3_dot; eps4_dot; ...
        C11_dot; C12_dot; C13_dot; C21_dot; C22_dot; C23_dot; C31_dot; C32_dot; C33_dot];

end
```

My lines where I calculate phi1, phi2, and then the if/else statement to find phi, are what I am struggling with.

I made sure that the variables defined in the function work, so for example, in the command window I typed in 'y(:,4)' and got the correct output. But whenever I try to use this within the functions i.e. 'phi1', it repeatedly outputs an incorrect value of '90.0000' until I stop it.

Where I define the 'N' variable, it is something similar, yet that one works without errors.

Does anyone have any ideas how to amend this issue?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Edit: The complete error message is as follows:

```
Undefined function or variable 'phi'.

Error in HW6_Q1 (line 85)
plot(t,phi)
```

Comment: What exactly are your `if` statements supposed to be doing?

Comment: They are supposed to be finding the correct quadrant of the angle, phi, since the cosine and sine values are double-valued. So out of the two angles that the inverse cosine produces (+/- phi1) and the two angles that the inverse sine produces (phi2, 180-phi2), I want the if/else statement to compare each possible pair, and whatever one is true to have the value of phi.     That is what it is supposed to be doing, but I'm sure it is not actually doing that since my error is defining phi, but not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Well, `phi1` and `phi2` are array of length 4393 and your `if` statements are comparing the entire arrays to each other and then assigning `phi` to one of the two arrays. This isn't what your intent is, obviously. I think what you're actually looking for is the function `cart2pol` but I am having a difficult time understanding the underlying dynamic equation (`kap`??).

Comment: Or maybe `cart2sph` since this is three dimensional.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will look into `cart2pol` and `cart2sph`. The `kap` is just another angle (kappa), but that value I always want to be positive (so I suppose I should add an absolute value to make it such). For my function, I aim use those 16 `_dot` equations to solve for the 16 variables. Then I want to use some of those variable (mainly `y(4)` through `y(7)` to determine other variables at the same instances of time

Comment: I guess I'm confused why the `N` variable I defined can use the `y(:,4:7)` variables, which leaves `N` as the correct length. I was then able to plot `N` vs `t` and produced a plot (but that code isn't shown here)

Comment: Where is this error produced? Please copy-paste the full error message, including the stack trace. Also try to shorten your code by removing things that are not related to your code, this makes it a lot easier to find the issue. See [mre].

Comment: I did remove a lot of the code, the reason I left what I did was because I wasn't sure what specifically caused the error. At any rate, this is the error message: `Undefined function or variable 'phi'.

Error in HW6_Q1 (line 85)
plot(t,phi)`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my solution with the help from a colleague not on Stack Overflow.

I forgot the `./`, which turned my phi into a matrix, rather than a vector which is what I wanted from it.